# Defining Piecewise Functions

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

I'm having trouble defining piecewise functions. What I have so far is a function that outputs something in a suitable format for `Piecewise`:

```
envpart = getpsipieces[LUs[[1]], LUs[[2]], eenv, ms, hbar]
```

> ```
> {{(0.707118 + 0. I) E^((-0.138441 + 0. I) x) + (0.707082 + 0.00436397 I) E^((0.138441 + 0. I) x), 
>   0 < x < 0.47619}, 
>  {(0.708113 + 0.0127916 I) E^((0. - 0.617118 I) (-0.47619 + x)) + 
>       (0.709159 - 0.00813024 I) E^((0. + 0.617118 I) (-0.47619 + x)), 
>   0.47619 < x < 0.524036}, 
>  {(0.755281 + 0.00032215 I) E^((-0.138441 + 0. I) (-0.524036 + x)) + (0.661991 + 
>       0.00436804 I) E^((0.138441 + 0. I) (-0.524036 + x)), 
>   0.524036 < x < 1.}}
> ```

What I want to be able to do is make a function that looks like

```
f[x_]:=Piecewise[envpart]
```

for simple plotting, integrating, etc.

When I try this, `f[x0]` returns `Piecewise[envpart]`, `f[x_]=Piecewise[envpart]` works, but it locks up `Piecewise` and I want three of these types of functions working at once.

`f[x_]=Piecewise[(writing out actual argument)]` works perfectly, but one of the functions I want to build has hundreds of cases, so this isn't feasible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Evaluate` for this purpose:

```
 f[x_] := Evaluate@Piecewise[envpart]
```

Make sure that `x` has no value assigned. `ClearAll[x]` before will handle this.

This operation is described in [`Evaluate` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html?q=Evaluate&lang=en). 3rd/4th example in `Applications` section.

Why it does not worki without it? `x` is scoped when creating the function and if you later provide `envpart` it's just different `x`. `Evaluate` provides it before it is scoped.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your quick response, concise solution and explanation.

Comment: @user12308 Please take a look at the link I've just found. Do not worry if question is closed. It will stay here as a link to the generic case.